# shutil error from Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, shutil

I am trying to copy a folder and all its content/structure with this command:

```
shutil.copytree('visualization_template', output)
```

If I run the script from a .py file, it works perfectly.
If I run the same script from a jupyter notebook, the above command returns me the following error:

```
    219     try:
--> 220         mkdir(name, mode)
    221     except OSError:
    222         # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system
```

how do I solve it?

Comment: It may sound silly, but are you sure you're not trying to create an existing directory? Is output different each time you run it?

Comment: Kola, if there is a silly one in here IT IS ME! You are right, I was trying to create an existing directory. But I also must add that it makes little sense to me given that I am actually using the following code that should cope with this kind of problem: while True:
    try:
        shutil.copytree('visualization_template', output)
        break
    except:
        output = output + '_' + str(i)
        i += 1
        if i > 100:
            break